# Validating example code snippets in a textarea using strict XHTML

Tags: validation, xhtml, textarea, strict

I am currently trying to post some code snippets inside of a textarea, within a strict XHTML document. I cannot for the life of me get these snippets to pass validation. I have a perfect xhtml strict document with the following.

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="80">
    <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
</textarea>
```

I have tried (what I assume) is every possible combination of the `<![CDATA[` tag to no avail.

including the following:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="80">
    <![CDATA[
        <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    ]]>
</textarea>
```

This would work; however, the cdata tag is shown in the text area!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the form-Tag to be content of the textarea simply encode < as &lt; " as &quot; & as &amp; and > as &gt;:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" xml:lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<textarea rows="10" cols="80">
    &lt;form method=&quot;post&quot; action=&quot;<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>&quot;&gt;
</textarea>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP can do the encoding for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" xml:lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<textarea rows="10" cols="80">
    <?php
    $html = <<<HTML
<form method="post" action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}">
HTML;
    echo htmlspecialchars($html);
    ?>
</textarea>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```